# How to secure cookies in php?

Tags: php, security, session-cookies

How does `session_set_cookie_params` work?
I want to ensure all cookies are set with `httponly=true`, and `secure=true`.
But instead of adding these arguments to every call to setcookie(), I can
just - before session_start() - set them in `session_set_cookie_params()`?
And henceforth, every call to `setcookie` sets those `params` i each and every cookie?
That would save a lot of tedious work (and surely error-prone).
I would imagine something like this

```
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$cookieParams['httponly'] = true;
$cookieParams['secure'] = true;
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams);
session_start();
```

So now, if I do:

```
 setcookie("ABC_user", "", time()+3600);
```

That cookie has those params in argument 6 and 7 set? Is there a way to check that it works? Or is there an even better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params` only influences the session id cookie, that gets set by `session_start` (or any other actually session-related functions, that might regenerate the session id cookie.) The general `setcookie` function has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with that in the first place.

Comment: If you want your normal cookies set with specific extra parameters, without having to write them out every time - then you probably best create your own wrapper function, that calls `setcookie` with those explicitly specified values.

Comment: Thank you very much for that info. I had a suspicion that my vision was too good to be true... :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code will give you what you want.

```
function set_cookie($name,$content,$time){
$http_only = true;
$secure = true;
$path = "/";
$domain = ".example.com"; // Include All Subdomains
setcookie($name,$content,$time,$path,$domain,$secure,$http_only);
}

set_cookie("ABC_user", "", time() + 3600);
```

Comment: WhereIsBurak: Something like that, yes. I prefer to keep the default argument values exactly as-is, from the php documentation. But it saves my day. Thank you.
I'll set this as the accepted answer.